# Do I have to start the SSH authentication agent every time I log in to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have noticed that I when I log into my EC2 instance, I have to start the authentication agent and then add my private key to SSH before I can git pull code into my instance. Is there a better way to do this than typing:

```
eval "$ssh-agent"
ssh-add path-to-my-private-key
```

Seems like I am either doing this wrong or don't have the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If your private key is encrypted (=protected with a passphrase), what it definitely should be(!), you have to be prompted for the passphrase, so that SSH can decrypt it. There's no way to make it more automatic.

Only if your key is not encrypted (not recommended), you can use it without any interaction by adding your command to your account profile script.

Comment: Martin - thank you for this. Yes - private key is encrypted. Maybe I can write a bash script for it.

Comment: @Nuhuxi Sure. But you still need to (should) enter the passphrase manually.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. But I found this:

http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

And that eliminated the need to do what I was doing - thanks for the comments and help.